# (specific resource) AWS Lambda:The provided execution role does not have permissions to call DescribeNetworkInterfaces on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, policy

I know that I can fix this policy with AWS managed role or wildcard on resource, but my question is:
¿How can I specify what is the resource performing those actions over ec2:?

I want to set specific lambda to perform those actions in my policy, like this.
I've tried, but is throwing same error above, it only works if I place * for resource.

```
{
    Action   = [
        "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
        "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
        "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
        "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
        "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
        "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
        "ec2:ResetNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
    ]
    Effect   = "Allow"
    Resource = "arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<acc_id>:function:myfunction"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when defining an IAM policy, the `Resource` is where these actions are applied to, rather than who can perform these actions. So the `Resource` here wouldn't be a lambda, but would be some EC2 resources. The resource that performs these actions (your lambda) is where you attach the IAM role.

That being said, not all EC2 actions have resource-level permissions, and `DescribeNetworkInterfaces` is one that doesn't. This means that you wouldn't be able to specify a specific resource for this action, and have to use `'*'`.

References:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policy-structure.html#ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html

Comment: Excellent answer this clear lot of things to me. Thanks